# Exception message trying to obtain the Window handle of a process

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, linq, process

I'm trying to make a generic function to obtain the main window handle of a process, giving the process handle,
I want to use LINQ (avoid the usage of FOR) but it throws an exception of 'Denied access' at the 'Where' clausule.

I'm doing something wrong?

```
Private Function Get_Process_MainWindowHandle(ByVal ProcessHandle As IntPtr) As IntPtr

    Try
        Return Process.GetProcesses _
               .Where(Function(p) p.Handle.Equals(ProcessHandle)) _
               .Cast(Of Process) _
               .First _
               .MainWindowHandle

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message) ' ex Message: Access denied
        Return IntPtr.Zero
    End Try

End Function
```

Usage:

```
Get_Process_MainWindowHandle(Process.GetProcessesByName("calc").First.Handle)
```

> UPDATE:

In this other Function that I'm trying to do I get the same exception, and more than that, the main window handle is not found, what I'm doing wrong?:

```
Private Sub Resize_Process_Window(ByVal ProcessHandle As IntPtr, _
                                  ByVal Weight As Integer, _
                                  ByVal Height As Integer)

    Dim rect As Rectangle = Nothing
    Dim procs As Process() = Nothing
    Dim hwnd As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero

    Try
        ' Find the process
        procs = Process.GetProcesses

        For Each p As Process In procs
            Try
                If p.Handle.Equals(ProcessHandle) Then
                    MsgBox("Handle found!") ' Msgbox will never be displayed :(
                    hwnd = p.MainWindowHandle
                    Exit For
                End If
            Catch : End Try ' Catch for 'Denied acces' Win32Exception.
        Next

        Msgbox(hwnd) ' hwnd always is '0'   :(

        ' Store the Left, Right, Bottom and Top positions of Window, into the Rectangle.
        GetWindowRect(hwnd, rect)

        ' Resize the Main Window
        MoveWindow(hwnd, rect.Left, rect.Top, Weight, Height, True)

    Catch ex As InvalidOperationException
        'Throw New Exception("Process not found.")
        MessageBox.Show("Process not found.", Nothing, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    Finally
        rect = Nothing
        procs = Nothing
        hwnd = Nothing

    End Try

End Sub
```

Usage:

```
Resize_Process_Window(Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").First.Handle, 500, 500)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem: You are trying to access the Handle of processes for which you do not have the necessary permission. Usually, this is the System and Idle processes, but depending on who you're running as there could well be others.

Your `GetProcesses()` LINQ query will be trying to access the Handle of every process to establish whether or not they match the inclusion criteria. If you want to get a list of processes that you do have Handle access to, you could do something like the following. Sorry this is C# not VB, but you should find it trivial to convert it:

```
        private void EnumeratePermittedProcesses()
        {

            Process[] Procs = Process.GetProcesses();

            foreach (Process P in Procs)
            {
                try
                {
                    IntPtr Ptr = P.Handle;
                    Debug.WriteLine("Processed Process " + P.ProcessName);
                }
                catch (Exception Ex)
                {
                    // Ignore forbidden processes so we can get a list of processes we do have access to
                }
            }
        }
```

Secondly, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.handle.aspx) tells us that process handles are not unique so you shouldn't be using them for comparison using .Equals. Use Process Id instead. This *is* unique and has the added advantage that you won't get an access denied error when asking for the `Id` Property.

Here's how you would get the IntPtr whilst avoiding accessing the Handle of processes you don't have permission to access:

```
        private IntPtr GetMainWindowHandle(int processId)
        {

            Process[] Procs = Process.GetProcesses();

            foreach (Process P in Procs)
            {              
                if (P.Id == processId )
                {                    
                    MessageBox.Show("Process Id Found!");

                    return P.MainWindowHandle;
                }                                       
            }

            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }
```

Usage:

```
IntPtr P = GetMainWindowHandle(Process.GetProcessesByName("calc").First().Id);
```

Again, you'll need to convert to VB (I'm a little rusty).